# Cannot convert from 'ref [Inherited]' to 'ref [Base]' for a function

Tags: c#, inheritance

Base class:

```
abstract class Base_strategy
    {
    public Base_strategy()
        {
        EnemyLastTurn = Choices.NULL;
        score = 0;
        }

    static public void compare(ref Base_strategy player1, ref Base_strategy player2)
        {
        /* stuff */
        }

    abstract protected Choices firstTurn();
    abstract protected Choices defectedLastTurn();
    abstract protected Choices cooperatedLastTurn();

    protected Choices EnemyLastTurn;

    public int score;

    public abstract void addScore_Sucker();
    public abstract void addScore_Traitor();
    public abstract void addScore_Punishment();
    public abstract void addScore_Reward();
    }
```

Inherited class:

```
 class titfortat_strategy : Base_strategy
    {
    titfortat_strategy()
        {

        }
 /* overridden functions */

    }
```

Code:

```
titfortat_strategy p1, p2;
Base_strategy.compare(ref p1, ref p2);
```

The error is `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref titfortat_strategy' to 'ref Base_strategy'`
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref titfortat_strategy' to 'ref Base_strategy'`

I'm not sure why it doesn't work. It seems like it should, though... `compare()` calls functions that are inherited from `Base_strategy` to `titfortat_strategy` only, and has to change the internal state of the arguments, hence the `ref`. 
If more information is needed, please comment and I'll do my best to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ref` parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) are almost never necessary.

> `compare()` calls functions that are inherited from `Base_strategy`… only

In this case you don't need it. `Base_strategy` is a class so `player1` and `player2` are already references to their respective objects. Just change it to:

```
static public void compare(Base_strategy player1, Base_strategy player2)
{
    /* stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because it is not safe. If it were allowed you could do:

```
public class OtherStrategy : Base_strategy { }
titfortat_strategy ts = null;


static public void compare(ref Base_strategy player1, ref Base_strategy player2)
{
    player1 = new OtherStrategy();
}
```

which assigns an `OtherStrategy` instance to a reference of type `titfortat_strategy`.

The solution is just to change the types of `p1` and `p2` to match:

```
Base_strategy p1, p2;
Base_strategy.compare(ref p1, ref p2);
```

Another possibility is that you may not need to use `ref` at all - you only need to use it in your `compare` method if you need to modify the caller's `p1` and `p2` variables inside 
`compare`.

Answer (score 1):

`ref` is not for "changing the internal state of the arguments", it is for reassigning arguments to point to totally different objects.

Consider what would happen if you could pass `ref p1`, the function could then execute

```
player1 = new other_strategy();
```

and violate type safety, since `p1` in the caller would not longer be a `titfortat_strategy`.